# A basic question on equilibrium points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

consider the follwoing ODE $x'(t) = h(x(t))$ where $h$ is lipschitz continuous. Now, what is the initial condition do we need so that the trajectory  1)reaches an equilibrium points 2) converges to an equilibrium point.

Comment: That rather depends on $h$.

Comment: What is the relation between equilibrium points and solutions, and what does the Lipschitz condition tell about uniqueness?